# Detectar registros duplicados en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Quiero encontrar registros que sean exactamente iguales en todos sus campos y mostrarlos.
Tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image]

Aplico la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT * 
FROM control 
WHERE (no IN(SELECT no 
             FROM control 
             GROUP BY no
             HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
       ) 
      AND (clave IN(SELECT clave 
                    FROM control  
                    GROUP BY clave 
                    HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
          ) 
      AND (nombre IN(SELECT nombre 
                     FROM control
                     GROUP BY nombre 
                     HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
          )
      AND (resultado IN(SELECT resultado
                        FROM control 
                        GROUP BY resultado 
                        HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
          )
```

Pero como resultado me arroja esto:

[image]

Solo me debería arrojar los primeros cuatro ya que coinciden en todos sus campos.

Comment: Has probado con una consulta así? `SELECT no, clave, nombre, resultado FROM control group by no, clave, nombre, resultado HAVING COUNT() > 1`

Comment: y DISTINCTROW no anda por algo en particular?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar la siguiente consulta, usando la clausula GROUP BY y HAVING.

```
SELECT * FROM `prueba` GROUP BY no,clave,nombre,resultado HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]